# ctypes from buffer - Python

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I'm using ctypes to convert from a binary data buffer

```
log = DataFromBuffe.from_buffer(buffer)
```

in my class i have

```
class DataFromBuffe(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
_pack_ = 1
_fields_ = [
        ('id', ctypes.c_char * 1),
        ('name', ctypes.c_char * 30),
        ('value', ctypes.c_double),
        ('size', ctypes.c_uint16),
        ('date', type(datetime.datetime))
        ]
```

But I have two problems?

1 - How can I work with datetime? Fild 'date' is not working.

2 - Field 'size', for some reason is BigEndian. Is it possible change structure just for this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 - How can I work with datetime? Fild 'date' is not working.

Your `date` field **must** be a `ctypes` type (or a type inheriting from a `ctypes` type). This means you have to find a way to express a date as a number (int, float, double, whatever you want, but it can not be a non-ctypes python type).

In this example I used the well known [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (which can be represented on a `ctypes.c_uint32`)

```py
class DataFromBuffer(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('id', ctypes.c_char * 1),
        ('name', ctypes.c_char * 30),
        ('value', ctypes.c_double),
        ('size', ctypes.c_uint16),
        ('date', ctypes.c_uint32),  # date as a 32-bit unsigned int.
    ]

# snip

    now_date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    now_int = int(now_date_time.timestamp())  # now as an integer (seconds from the unix epoch)
    print(f"Now - datetime: {now_date_time!s}; int: {now_int}")

    test_buffer = (b"A" + # id
        # snip
        now_int.to_bytes(4, "little")  # date
    )
```

As for the conversion to a datetime, I simply added a function member to the structure so it can convert the date (a `ctypes.c_uint32`) to a datetime:

```py
    def date_to_datetime(self) -> datetime.datetime:
        """Get the date field as a python datetime.
        """
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(self.date)
```

> 2 - Field 'size', for some reason is BigEndian. Is it possible change structure just for this field?

No it's not possible. A possible way is to have a function or property to access the field as you want it to be (performing some sort of conversion under the hood):

```py
    def real_size(self) -> int:
        """Get the correct value for the size field (endianness conversion).
        """
        # note: there multiple way of doing this: bytearray.reverse() or struct.pack and unpack, etc.
        high = self.size & 0xff
        low = (self.size & 0xff00) >> 8
        return high | low
```

---

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ctypes
import math
import datetime

class DataFromBuffer(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('id', ctypes.c_char * 1),
        ('name', ctypes.c_char * 30),
        ('value', ctypes.c_double),
        ('size', ctypes.c_uint16),
        ('date', ctypes.c_uint32),
    ]

    def date_to_datetime(self) -> datetime.datetime:
        """Get the date field as a python datetime.
        """
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(self.date)

    def real_size(self) -> int:
        """Get the correct value for the size field (endianness conversion).
        """
        # note: there multiple way of doing this: bytearray.reverse() or struct.pack and unpack, etc.
        high = self.size & 0xff
        low = (self.size & 0xff00) >> 8
        return high | low

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = b"foobar"
    now_date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    now_int = int(now_date_time.timestamp())  # now as an integer (seconds from the unix epoch)
    print(f"Now - datetime: {now_date_time!s}; int: {now_int}")

    test_buffer = (b"A" + # id
        name + (30 - len(name)) * b"\x00" +  # name (padded with needed \x00)
        bytes(ctypes.c_double(math.pi)) +  # PI as double
        len(name).to_bytes(2, "big") +  # size (let's pretend it's the name length)
        now_int.to_bytes(4, "little")  # date (unix epoch)
    )

    assert ctypes.sizeof(DataFromBuffer) == len(test_buffer)

    data = DataFromBuffer.from_buffer(bytearray(test_buffer))
    print(f"date: {data.date}; as datetime: {data.date_to_datetime()}")
    print(f"size: {data.size} ({data.size:#x}); real size: {data.real_size()} ({data.real_size():#x})")
```

---

output:

```
Now - datetime: 2019-07-31 14:52:21.193023; int: 1564577541
date: 1564577541; as datetime: 2019-07-31 14:52:21
size: 1536 (0x600); real size: 6 (0x6)
```